# Investigating the Effect of Launch Angle on Drag Coefficient at Terminal Velocity of Paper Planes

Tags: thermodynamics

How does the angle of launch of the paper plane with respect to the horizontal (0 °,20 °,40 °,60 °,80 °) affect the drag coeffect measured at terminal velocity?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.